# How can I fillna, using the nearest value, within each day?

Tags: python, pandas

I have precipitation forecasts, but it is only forecasted for the morning and for the evening:

```
2022-06-08 00:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 01:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 02:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 03:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 04:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 05:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 06:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 07:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 08:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 09:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 10:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 11:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 12:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 13:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 14:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 15:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 16:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 17:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 18:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 19:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 20:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 21:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 22:00:00     NaN
2022-06-08 23:00:00     NaN
2022-06-09 00:00:00     NaN
2022-06-09 01:00:00     NaN
2022-06-09 02:00:00     NaN
2022-06-09 03:00:00     NaN
2022-06-09 04:00:00     NaN
2022-06-09 05:00:00     NaN
2022-06-09 06:00:00     NaN
2022-06-09 07:00:00    0.01
```

Since each forecast is a daily forecast, I only want to fillna within each day. I could do

```
df['precipitation'] = df['precipitation'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'D')).ffill().bfill()
```

but that overweights the morning forecast and underweights the evening. I want to do something like

```
df['precipitation'] = df['precipitation'].interpolate(method = 'nearest')
```

but group it by the date, so that the forecast doesn't spill over into another day (for which it was not intended). The desired output is something like:

```
2022-06-08 00:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 01:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 02:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 03:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 04:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 05:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 06:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 07:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 08:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 09:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 10:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 11:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 12:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 13:00:00    0.03
2022-06-08 14:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 15:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 16:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 17:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 18:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 19:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 20:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 21:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 22:00:00    0.00
2022-06-08 23:00:00    0.00
2022-06-09 00:00:00    0.01
2022-06-09 01:00:00    0.01
2022-06-09 02:00:00    0.01
2022-06-09 03:00:00    0.01
2022-06-09 04:00:00    0.01
2022-06-09 05:00:00    0.01
2022-06-09 06:00:00    0.01
2022-06-09 07:00:00    0.01
```

Comment: how do you get the `0.03`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply interpolate to your groups:

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'D')).apply(pd.DataFrame.interpolate, method = 'nearest')`

or using a lambda function

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'D')).apply(lambda group: group.interpolate(method = 'nearest'))`

Be aware that the performance will likely be awful on a large dataframe